# Selected item in SelectList not being displayed in view drop-down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, default, selectlist

I have an asp.net MVC application in which I have a Razor view for creating a new event. On the form is a drop-down list of seasons for the user to select from. I would like the current season to be pre-selected in this list as a default.

I have set up two seasons:

**Season 1** is for 2020-2021 and has its IsCurrent property set to False;
**Season 2** is for 2021-2022 and has its IsCurrent property set to True

**Controller code...**

```
ViewData["Seasons"] = new SelectList(_context.Seasons, "ID", "SeasonName",_context.Seasons.Where(s => s.IsCurrent==true));
```

**View...**

```
<select asp-for="SeasonID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Seasons"></select>
```

When I run this, I am expecting to see the season 2021-2022 pre-selected in the drop-down, but it just shows 2020-2021 (being the first in the list).

This seems like it should be so simple - can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one has bitten me a few times in the past, all the way back to MVC 3 or so.

Basically, if you're passing a model to your view (i.e. using a `@model MyTypeOfViewModel` directive) and binding a `select` to a property on that model, then the selected value of the select list is the *value of the property you are binding to on your view model*. Setting the selected item in a select list directly **will be ignored**.

In your case, it's `SeasonID` from this:

```
<select asp-for="SeasonID" ...>
```

So for you to select `Season 2`, you'd need to set the value of the `SeasonID` property on your view model to the `ID` of `Season 2`:

```
var viewModel = new SeasonViewModel
{
    SeasonID = // Season 2's SeasonID
}
```

However, if you're *not* binding the value of the `select` directly, creating the `select` like this:

```
// Notice I've not specified `asp-for`.
<select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Seasons"></select>
```

will use the selected value you set when creating the `SelectList`. That said, your code to do that is currently slightly wrong. It should be:

```
var selected = _context.Seasons
    .Where(s => s.IsCurrent == true)
    .FirstOrDefault();
ViewData["Seasons"] = new SelectList(
                _context.Seasons,
                "ID",
                "SeasonName",
                // It needs to be the actual value of the field, not the season's object.
                selected?.ID.ToString());
```

---

In short, if you want to bind to your `SeasonID` property, create your `SelectList`, without selecting a value, like so:

```
ViewData["Seasons"] = new SelectList(
            _context.Seasons,
            "ID",
            "SeasonName");
```

Then set the selected value on the view model itself, and the `asp-for` attribute on the select will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks so much John H - it's now fixed!
Your corrections to the controller code sorted it out (using FirstOrDefault() and using the Season.ID rather than the Season object).
I can still get away with using asp-for, I guess because it's a create - not an edit - view, so the selected item is not overridden by any binding data value.
Thanks again for your brilliantly explained answer.

Comment: @DivZero You're welcome, and thanks for the additional information.